# CMake (win) mysql c++ connector - cant find mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, connector

i'm trying to build the c++ connector for VS 2012 with CMake.
It's searching for the MySQL Directory but it can't find it.

```
C:\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.3>cmake -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=C:\cpp\boost
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  A logical block opening on the line

    C:/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.3/CMakeLists.txt:39 (if)

  closes on the line

    C:/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.3/CMakeLists.txt:41 (endif)

  with mis-matching arguments.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Environment compile flags:
-- Environment link flags:
-- Boost version: 1.53.0
-- BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS=C:/cpp/boost
-- ENV{MYSQL_DIR} =
**CMake Error at FindMySQL.cm:220 (MESSAGE):
  Cannot find MySQL.  Include dir: MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND library dir:**
  cxxflags:
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:173 (INCLUDE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Is there a way to set it manual by hand?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course: if you know where your MySql include directories are located (say `C:\MySql\include` for example), just call CMake with the following `-D` option:

```
cmake -DMYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\MySql\include
```

The `-D` command line option defines a CMake constant with a given value if needed. When CMake can not find a variable and you know which value it should have, you should give it to CMake with `-D` when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the MySQL files you need are found in the **Program Files** folder.
In my case I installed the MySQL C Connector to the default location that is in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1`.

You can follow the steps from this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20281600/2871838) to compile the MySQL C++ Connector on Visual Studio 2012.

Note: If you do not want it to be 64bit then on the `cmake` call change `-G "Visual Studio 11 Win64"` to `-G "Visual Studio 11"`.

Answer (score -1):

Adding MYSQL_DIR to my computer's environment variables solved the problem.

This dir should be set to MySQL server's dir, to me it is "E:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"

Hope it helps.