# MySQL Connector C++ 64bit build from source in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, mysql-connector

I am trying to build the **mySQL Connector C++** from source in **Visual Studio 2012** for the **64-bit** architecture.
I understand that it depends on some **boost** header files and the **C connector.**
Running **CMake** produces a project file, but that project file doesn't compile because of a big list of very confusing errors which probably have to do something with the include files, and an even bigger list of warnings. The official site is of little help.

Could some one please list all the steps in successfully compiling the C++ Connector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to build it you need to have the following:

1. You need to have installed either the MySQL server or the [MySQL C Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/).
2. Have installed the [Boost C++ libraries](http://www.boost.org/) or have the source files for it. Please note that there is not need to build boost as you only need the header files.
3. Have [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) installed. When installing CMake it will ask you if you want it included in the `PATH` variable, you should select yes to make it easier later to use it.

Once you have all three available, open **VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt** and  from the source root directory of the MySQL C++ Connector you need to issue the following:

```
set MYSQL_DIR=c:\PROGRA~1\MySQL\MYSQLC~1.1
cmake -G "Visual Studio 11 Win64" ^
      -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=C:\Users\user\DOWNLO~1\BOOST_~1\BOOST_~1 ^
      -DMYSQL_LIB_DIR:STRING=c:\PROGRA~1\MySQL\MYSQLC~1.1\LIB
devenv.com MySQLCPPCONN.sln /build Release
```

The first command defines the `MYSQL_DIR` variable that points to the installation of the MySQL server or the MySQL C Connector.
The second command call cmake to prepare a VS project that will be 64bit. There seems to be a problem with the `MYSQL_LIB_DIR` variable and it does not get generated, so we need to define it manually. `MYSQL_LIB_DIR` has the value of `MYSQL_DIR` ending with a `\LIB`.
Third command is optional, it will build the project from command prompt without opening VS.

It is recommended that you use the DOS paths for the variables.
To do that, navigate to the directory you want to convert to DOS path and call `for %I in (.) do echo %~sI`. It will give you the converted path.

Comment: It actually worked! It compiled for both Release and Debug. 216 Warnings still remained mostly saying `xxx needs to have dll-interface` but the library compiled and liked fine!! :)

Comment: Note that you need to select "source code" in the drop down list while downloading on http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/.
That might seem stupid but I missed it.

Comment: I tried to use `-G="Visual Studio 14 2015"` and when I try to build the solution, I get 141 errors and 357 warnings. It dives me crazy.

Answer (score 4):

It's really tough task and I've spent lot of hours figuring this out.

There are two issues here:

1. C++ Connector and MySQL libraries they have provided have been generated with Visual Studio 2010. Hence we can not use them as it is under VS2012 (It gives version mismatch error)
2. They also have not specified exact compiler options under which they have compiled these libraries. If our compiler settings are different, we'll end up in lots and lots of (especially linker related) errors.

Considering these facts, the only way is to build ourselves these libraries. Building MySQL is quick but building connector is little complicated.

Here are steps I am sharing. In my case I wanted to link these libraries statically with my project so I built these libraries accordingly. You may want to make relevant changes wherever necessary as per your need.

Before continuing with these steps, please download and install CMake on your system.

**Steps to build MySQL server:**

1. Download MySQL source. Extract them. Go in extracted folder in command prompt.
2. Create BLD forder
3. Go in BLD folder through command prompt
4. Run

   ```
   cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 11 2012 Win64"
   ```

   It will create MySQL.sln
5. Open MySQL.sln in Visual Studio and build only 'mysqlclient' library (as only this would be needing by application)

This will build libraries in mysql-5.6.24\BLD\libmysql\< Configuration > folder which we link in our project.

**Steps to build C++ connector:**

1. Download mysql-connector-c++ source. Extract it. Go in extracted folder in command prompt.
2. Create BLD forder
3. Go in BLD folder through command prompt
4. Run this command (Make sure we've built MySQL server before this, in Release and Debug mode. Also make sure we've downloaded Boost sources)

   ```
   cmake .. -DMYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR="..\..\mysql-5.6.24\include" -DMYSQL_LIB_DIR:STRING="..\mysql-5.6.24\BLD\libmysql\Release" -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING="..\Boost\boost_1_54_0" -DMYSQL_CLIENT_STATIC_LINKING=1 -G "Visual Studio 11 2012 Win64"
   ```

   It will create MYSQLCPPCONN.sln
5. Open MYSQLCPPCONN.sln in Visual Studio and make changes to 'mysqlcppconn-static' project:

   A. Under C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories put this (for All Configurations)

   ```
     nativeapi;..\;..\..\;..\cppconn;..\..\cppconn;..\..\..\mysql-5.6.24\include;..\..\..\mysql-5.6.24\BLD\include;..\..\..\Boost\boost_1_54_0
   ```

   B. In Code Genaration, change Runtime Library to Multithreaded (Debug or non-Debug depends on configuration) and NOT DLL

   C. Under Librarian -> All Options keep "Additional Options" and "Ignore Specific Default Libraries" to blank (for All Configurations)

   D. Under Librarian -> General keep "Ignore Specific Default Libraries" to blank (for All Configurations)
6. Build only 'mysqlcppconn-static' library project (as only this would be needing by application to connect to MySQL server)

This would generate library in mysql-connector-c++-1.1.5\BLD\driver\< Configuration > folder which we link in our project.

Comment: Do you have a step for Visual Studio 2013 and non static Connector build steps?

Comment: I never tried that but if you share what problems are you facing if you repeat these same steps for VS2013 (with cmake option `-DMYSQL_CLIENT_STATIC_LINKING=0` for non-static linking) ?

Comment: I was able to build the connector with cmake .. -DMYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR="D:\WEBSER~1\mysql\MYSQLS~1.6\include" -DMYSQL_LIB_DIR:STRING="D:\WEBSER~1\mysql\MYSQLS~1.6\lib" -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING="D:\BOOST_~2" -DMYSQL_CLIENT_STATIC_LINKING=0 -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"

Comment: Your step to build the mysql server is confusing. You just do cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 11 2012 Win64"? There is no linking? for example -DMYSQL_CLIENT_STATIC_LINKING=0.....

Comment: After MYSQLCPPCONN.sln  is generated, I opened it and went to property to do step 5 but  C/C+ is not showing up. So I can't add \cppconn and the rest to the Additional Include Directories

Comment: Never mind. I fixed all the problems by trying George Michael's solution. Thanks.

Comment: Once it generates MySQL.sln we can change linker/compiler configuration the way we want through Visual Studio. The same applies to MYSQLCPPCONN.sln. But here we given additional parameters to cmake so that we get header/library directories in solution and we don't need to add them afterwards through Visual Studio. But we still can always make any linker/compiler config change to .sln afterwards. George Michael's solution assumes you have MySQL installed so you don't need to build MySQL. However you may get linker errors if MySQL lib that comes with installation differs in version.

Comment: Even though Georges' answer worked, I tried yours again and it worked. It seems like it worked the first time but I didn't know where the generated files where. Thanks for your help.